# What in the Cast, is different

Tags: c#

This could be a trivial question, I've seen several different variations of *Cast*.

- What is the difference?
- Is one better than another (Performance)?
- Is it just a matter of preference, code legibility?

**Example One:**

```
command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

**Example Two:**

```
(string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Both will impact the `ExecuteScalar()` differently, so the question is when interacting with the database is one more ideal than another?

Comment: `as` will fail gracefully.

Comment: @kirinthos `[displayText](linkUrl)`. Also how did you manage to comment, you have under 50 rep. Did the flagging dialogue make that?

Comment: i can finally comment, it auto-converted my answer to a comment, which i then couldn't edit/delete, because i couldn't do comment stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first ( `command.ExecuteScalar() as string;` )will do a runtime *attempt* to convert the result of `ExecuteScalar()` into a string.  If the resulting type is not a `string`, you will receive `null`.  The as keyword also only performs reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions, so you can't use it directly with non nullable value types.

The second ( `(string)command.ExecuteScalar();` ) will do a conversion to `string` directly, and raise an `InvalidCastException` if the resulting value is not a `string`.

> Is one better than another (Performance)?

In general, using the second option should provide (insignificantly) better performance if you know the result is always going to be a string.

> Is it just a matter of preference, code legibility?

This is where I make the stronger differentiation.  Using `as` suggests that the result may not be a string, and you will be handling the `null` check.  Using a direct cast suggests that you know it's always a string, and anything else is an error and should raise an exception.

In my opinion, this should be the deciding factor for which to choose, since it shows your intent directly in the code.

Comment: It would be good to point out that `as` will work only if the type being casted to is known to be a reference type or a nullable value type.

Comment: `as` will produce a compiler error in the case of value types (just clarifying the type of "it won't work")

Comment: @JeffMercado Just edited to include that information.

Answer (score 4):

`(string)command.ExecuteScalar()` will throw an exception if `command.ExecuteScalar()` cannot be cast.

`command.ExecuteScalar() as string` will just return null instead.